Automated software installation
This is a Python code I generated using Chat GPT. Basically, I want the program to run all of the software installation automatically. For example, user doesn't need to click multiple next buttons when they just want to install the VLC media player. The software setups are local files.
The code below can run and install software, but still requires clicking the next button. I tried to ask Chat GPT to solve it for me but it couldn't. I am wondering if anyone  here can help to troubleshoot the problem?
    import os
    import subprocess
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, messagebox

    def run_installation(folder_path, selected_setups):
    total_setups = len(selected_setups)
    progress_bar\['maximum'\] = total_setups

    for i, setup_file in enumerate(selected_setups, start=1):
        setup_path = os.path.join(folder_path, setup_file)
        subprocess.Popen(setup_path, shell=True).wait()
        progress_bar['value'] = i
        root.update()
    
    messagebox.showinfo("Installation Complete", "All software installations have been completed.")

    def browse_folder():
    folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if folder_path:
    setup_files = \[f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.exe')\]
    if setup_files:
    folder_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    folder_entry.insert(tk.END, folder_path)
    software_listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
    for setup_file in setup_files:
    software_listbox.insert(tk.END, setup_file)
    else:
    messagebox.showinfo("No Software Found", "There are no software setups in the selected    folder.")

    def select_all():
    software_listbox.select_set(0, tk.END)

    def deselect_all():
    software_listbox.selection_clear(0, tk.END)

    def finish_installation():
    folder_path = folder_entry.get()
    selected_indices = software_listbox.curselection()
    selected_setups = \[software_listbox.get(idx) for idx in selected_indices\]
    if folder_path and selected_setups:
    run_installation(folder_path, selected_setups)

    # Create GUI

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Software Installer")

    frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="20")
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E, tk.N, tk.S))

    browse_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Browse", command=browse_folder)
    browse_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

    folder_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=50)
    folder_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)

    select_all_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Select All", command=select_all)
    select_all_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

    deselect_all_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Deselect All", command=deselect_all)
    deselect_all_button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)

    start_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Start Installation", command=finish_installation)
    start_button.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)

    software_listbox = tk.Listbox(frame, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE, width=50, height=10)
    software_listbox.grid(row=2, columnspan=3, pady=10)

    progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(frame, orient="horizontal", length=300, mode="determinate")
    progress_bar.grid(row=3, columnspan=3, pady=10)

    root.mainloop()


please edit the code and indent it properly.

some installers may allow to run with extra parameters and run without asking any questions or clicking Next. But you would have to search details on internet. For other installers you may need to use pyautogui or pynput to control mouse  and keyboard and send mouse click or press ENTER. On Windows you may also check pywin32 or pywinauto

Besides the indentation, that doesn't seem to be legal Python code - there are backslashes that don't belong, for example.

Also note that this has nothing to do with automated tests, per that tag's description.

It appears that you are trying to install on windows. If you use msi installers, you can install an .msi file silently, you should be able to use the /quiet switch with msiexec. If you need to customize anything, you can set property values like this: PROPERTY=Value
Altogether: msiexec /i C:\Path\To\File.msi /quiet PROPERTY=Value
To see all the options, just run msiexec without any parameters. Also take a look at this answer.
